# accessing lockscreen on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, lockscreen

Is there any possibility to operate with locksreen image in windowsPhone?
For example, writing some text on that image.
Acceptable solution is to draw some text as image on lockscreen wallpaper. I just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to programmatically access the lockscreen or set its image. You can create an image and save it to the Photo hub using [MediaLibrary.SavePicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.savepicture.aspx), but the user will still have to manually set that image as the wallpaper.